# EF Code First : One to Many relationship update the navigation object

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

Let me explain my question through an example:

I have the following entities:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public int? BranchId { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public Branch()
    {
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
    }
}
```

I have my DbContext as:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasMany<Project>(b => b.Projects).WithOptional(p => p.Branch).HasForeignKey(p => p.BranchId);
    }
}
```

The Branch and Project entities are added / updated / deleted from different contexts. Project comes into existence without a Branch, but after some workflow, the Project needs to be attached to a Branch from the list of Branches given.

If I try this, it works fine:

```
    private void ForeignKeyTest()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var project = db.Projects.Find(1);
            project.BranchId = 8;

            db.SaveChanges();

            var msg = project.Branch.BranchName; //call to the Branch after save

            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

But, if I try this, I get a NullReference Exception:

```
    private void ForeignKeyTest()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var project = db.Projects.Find(1);
            project.BranchId = 8;

            var msg = project.Branch.BranchName; //call to the Branch before save

            db.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

Now, I understand this is sort of expected behaviour because the Branch property of Project is not initialized. **But my question is, how to force update the Branch after getting the BranchId before the Project is saved** (some processing with the Project still remains at this point, so cannot save just to get to the Branch). Hope I explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two way to accomplish the goal.

First is to explicitly force (re)loading the navigation property in question by using the [`DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty>.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry%602.Load%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6%29%3Bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
var project = db.Projects.Find(1);
project.BranchId = 8;
db.Entry(project).Reference(e => e.Branch).Load(); // <--
var branchName = project.Branch.Name;
```

Second is to force updating all modified navigation properties by using the [`DbChangeTracker.DetectChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.DetectChanges%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6%29%3Bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
var project = db.Projects.Find(1);
project.BranchId = 8;
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // <--
var branchName = project.Branch.Name;
```

Both methods work in your scenario, but the first is more reliable - works with or without proxies and also for new entities (e.g. `db.Projects.Add`).

Comment: Hi Ivan Stoev! Thanks for the answer. Both the options are working perfectly fine. However, I have another question. If I only have public access to a DbSet<Project> property of a Repository (which hides the DbContext), can the same be achieved ?

Comment: Unfortunately you need access to `DbContext`, and `DbSet<T>` does not expose the `DbContext` it is bound to (although it internally has reference to it).

Comment: Instead, I think I can add a method "DetectChanges()" to my repository which in turn will call the same method on DbContext it is holding as a protected property. I don't want to expose the DbContext to the calling code. Is it acceptable?

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Hi Ivan Stoev. After giving a thought to your edit about the first option being more reliable, I have come up with the following on my base repository, but needs testing. Please have a look and comment. '        public void LoadChild<TChild>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, TChild>> child) where TChild : PersistentEntity
        {
            Db.Entry(entity).Reference(child).Load();
        }
'

Comment: Hi, once you want to hide the `DbContext`, this also works of course.